# How to set PATH correctly for docker-compose?

Tags: linux, docker-compose

I guess I am stuck with some very naive error here:

```bash
$ which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose

$ /usr/local/bin/docker-compose version
Docker Compose version v2.24.0-birthday.10

$ docker-compose
-bash: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory

$ echo $PATH
/home/ubuntu/.local/bin:/home/ubuntu/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin:/opt/polaris:/opt/gradle/gradle-8.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/ws/Go-WS/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:

$ type docker-compose
docker-compose is hashed (/usr/local/bin/docker-compose)

$ cat /usr/bin/docker-compose
cat: /usr/bin/docker-compose: No such file or directory
```

This weirdness disappears after I reboot the instance.

What is wrong with my PATH?

Comment: My guess is `/usr/bin/docker-compose` exists but is a broken symlink.

Comment: What does `type docker-compose` output ?

Answer (score 0):

As John stated, there is nothing wrong with your $PATH, but more so the symlink. Uninstall and re-install docker-compose to see if that fixes it